# Extend super class that match Generics?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift2

I want to use Generics in super class, but when I create child class, I got error

```
reference to generic type 'A' requires arguments in <...>
```

How to define Child Class B?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

var str = "Hello, playground"

protocol MyProtocol{
    func protocolfunc()
}

class A <T:MyProtocol> {

}
class B :A{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `B` is supposed to be generic itself:

```
class B<T:MyProtocol> : A<T> { ... }
```

If `B` is not supposed to be generic then:

```
class SomeType : MyProtocol { ... }
class B : A<SomeType> { ... }
```

For example:

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.1 (700.1.101.6 700.1.76). Type :help for assistance.
  1> class A<T> {}
  2> class B : A<Int> {}
  3>  
  4> class B<T> : A<T> {}
```

Comment: Worked,and fully helped!

Comment: You should ask another question as this other issue is unrelated.